# Rails - save to database from external JSON on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am attempting to update database fields from an external JSON response using Ruby on Rails.  I would like this action to take place upon creation of a new record, as the data is relatively static.  In the future I'll need to tackle the ability to refresh the data, but that is for another day.

I have created the rails scaffolding using:

```
rails generate scaffolding hotel hotelId:integer hotelName:string hotelCity:string
```

I would like to create a new record using only the hotelId, send the hotelId in my URI request, and then update the hotelName and hotelCity field.

I'm stuck on both sending the request using the hotelId field, and saving the results.

hotel.rb Model:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.save_data_from_api
    api = Expedia::Api.new
    response = api.get_information({:hotelId => '@hotelID'}) 
    hotel_data = response.body
    hotel_parsed = JSON.parse(hotel_data.to_json)

    h = Hotel.new
    h.hotelName = hotel_parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelSummary']['name']
    h.hotelCity = hotel_parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelSummary']['city']
    h.save!
    h

end

end
```

Included in my hotels_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    @hotelID = Hotel.hotelID
  end
```

I have not updated the new.html.erb View because I did not know how or where to call the save_data_from_api method.

Incidentally, the Expedia API gem I'm using is located here: https://github.com/zaidakram/expedia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :save_data_from_api

  def save_data_from_api
    return if hotel_id.blank?
    api = Expedia::Api.new
    response = api.get_information({:hotelId => hotel_id}) 
    hotel_data = response.body
    hotel_parsed = JSON.parse(hotel_data.to_json)

    self.hotel_name = hotel_parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelSummary']['name']
    self.hotel_city = hotel_parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelSummary']['city']
  end

end
```

and then use like `Hotel.create(hotel_id: '33')`.

Note that I've changed your AR attribute names to be more Ruby-ish.

EDIT

Depending on what you're doing with your application, it may not be necessary or the best idea to add hotels from a controller. You might want to just load them from `rails console`, or, if you have a list of hotel IDs, using a Rake task.

However, if you want to load them from a controller, you can have:

```
# in controller:

def new; @hotel = Hotel.new; end

def create
  # note: if you're using Rails 4, use strong params here
  @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @hotel.save
      format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

And in your `new.html.erb`, something like:

```
<%= form_for @hotel do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :hotel_id %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great response.  I've updated my code as you suggested, and changed my AR attribute names as well.  I'm not clear on where I call `Hotel.create(hotel_id: 'n')`.  Can you offer more clarity on that point?

Comment: You might just want to call that line from `rails console` (for testing now). I added a little more info about what your controller might look like.